# MySQL Subquery not returning expected results

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with communities and their corresponding MLS map area. Some communities are large and take up multiple map areas.

I am attempting to do a query that returns the most common communities and their map area when passed multiple map areas.

The query I am trying for map areas 601 and 606 is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(community), mapArea FROM (
    SELECT community, mapArea
    FROM single_family
    GROUP BY community
    ORDER BY COUNT(community) DESC) AS query1
WHERE mapArea LIKE '601%' OR mapArea LIKE '606%' ORDER BY community
```

Example single_family Table Layout (actual table has over 60k rows):

```
community    mapArea
Solera       606 - Henderson
Solera       606 - Henderson
Solera       204 - East
Solera       606 - Henderson
Solera       202 - East
Anthem       606 - Henderson
Green Valley 601 - Henderson
Green Valley 601 - Henderson
Green Valley 606 - Henderson
Seven Hills  606 - Henderson
Seven Hills  606 - Henderson
```

If I run a count on the table it shows:

```
community      mapArea           countCommunity
Anthem         606 - Henderson   776
Solera         606 - Henderson   58
Solera         204 - East        6
Solera         202 - East        1
Green Valley   601 - Henderson   188
Green Valley   606 - Henderson   117
Seven Hills    606 - Henderson   372
```

When I run the above query for map areas 601 and 606 I get the following which is correct for some communites but the community of Solera for example is not listed:

```
community     mapArea
Anthem        606 - Henderson
Green Valley  601 - Henderson
Seven Hills   606 - Henderson
```

Since Solera has the most rows with the map area being 606 - Henderson, I am wondering what is wrong in the query to why it is not being included.

Any help to why this is not returning the expected results and what I have to do to get the expected results is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are grouping by `community`, which in result, might hide `mapArea` lines within the grouped lines. try this instead:

```
SELECT community, mapArea FROM (
    SELECT community, mapArea
    FROM single_family
    WHERE mapArea LIKE '601%' OR mapArea LIKE '606%' 
    GROUP BY community
    ORDER BY COUNT(community) DESC) AS query1
ORDER BY community
```

also, why using DISTINCT when you're really grouping by the same column ? the subquery will result in rows with distinct values of communities. using DISTINCT will just slow down the process

Comment: Thanks. Your query does show the Solera community now, but if I do a search for `mapArea` `204 - East` it shows up as well, which I don't want. I run into the problem with the `community` being in different `mapAreas`. Since `Solera` has the most rows with `606 - Henderson` I only want it showing up for a search for 606.

Comment: try adding HAVING mapArea LIKE '601%' OR mapArea LIKE '606%'  after group by

Comment: I added `HAVING mapArea..` and it returned the same results with Solera showing in 606,204 & 202. I then removed the `WHERE` clause and then it returns the same issue as my original query, with Solera not showing up in 606.

Comment: When you're using where mapArea like '601%' etc.. you're filtering mapAreas before performing a group-by. there is no way you'd get mapAreas other than the ones filtered. not sure what is going on there. I think i'd need more info regarding the table.

Answer (score 0):

Communities are in multiple map areas.  How do you intend to handle that?

Your outer query really isn't needed.  You can phrase your query as:

```
SELECT community, mapArea
FROM single_family
WHERE mapArea LIKE '601%' OR mapArea LIKE '606%'
GROUP BY community
ORDER BY community;
```

If you want all the `mapArea`s listed as one column, use `group_concat()`:

```
SELECT community, group_concat(mapArea) as MapAreas
FROM single_family
WHERE mapArea LIKE '601%' OR mapArea LIKE '606%'
GROUP BY community
ORDER BY community;
```

If you are content to have them on separate rows, include the column in the `group by`:

```
SELECT community, mapArea
FROM single_family
WHERE mapArea LIKE '601%' OR mapArea LIKE '606%'
GROUP BY community, MapArea
ORDER BY community;
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried the queries you posted and although they list the Solera community, it also shows up if I change the query to `mapArea` 204, just like the other answer on here. You are correct with your statement, "Communities are in multiple map areas". That seems to be the issue that has stumped me. Since Solera has the most rows with `mapArea` `606 - Henderson` I only want it showing up for a search for 606, not 204. I am wondering if a temp table is needed and a second query run on that?

Comment: @xrjohn . . . Your question already has several answers.  I think you should ask another question, with much more care on the rules that you want for generating your results.